# Can I safely delete the /System/Library/Keychains/SystemRootCertificates.keychain?

Tags: macos, security, certificate, keychain

I'd like to delete: /System/Library/Keychains/SystemRootCertificates.keychain

Is that safe?

Comment: What version of macOS?

Comment: Mojave (10.14.4)

Answer (score 3):

No.

Do not tamper with the contents of `/System`. They are managed by the operating system, and modifying them will cause problems.

In this case, removing this keychain is likely to cause most secure network requests -- including ones made internally by the operating system -- to fail. It may also interfere with code signing, which may make your computer fail to boot.

Comment: Thanks, @duskwuff! So, is there a way to get this file back into its default, new machine state? I'd like to get rid of all the stuff I mistakenly imported from my iCloud account?

Comment: This file is not associated with your iCloud account. You don't need to do anything with it.